# Guoy method derivation, or, how not to break math?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, differentiation, magnetostatics

I start from $d\vec{F}=\nabla(\vec{m}\vec{B})$, $\vec{M}=\frac{d\vec{m_i}}{dV}$,  and $\vec{M}=\frac{\chi_v}{\mu_o}\vec{B}$.

I write out the definition of the force, determine we're only interested in the vertical component, and that the radial magnetic field is small and therefore these  terms are negligible. I'm then left with $dF_x=\frac{\partial m_zB_z}{\partial x}$. If I use the other two starting equations to express the magnetic dipole moment, I get the following $dF_x=\frac{dV\chi_v}{\mu_o}\frac{\partial B_z^2}{\partial x}$.

If, however, I divide both sides with $dV$ and integrate with respect with $dV$, I end up missing a factor of 2 in the denominator $$\int dF_x=F_x=\frac{\chi_v}{\mu_o}\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial B_z^2}{\partial x}dx=-\frac{\chi_v B_{zo}^2}{\mu_o}$$
The only other derivation of the Guoy method that I've found at one point assumes the dipole magnet moment is constant, and then the factor of 2 appears when they push the $B_z$ back inside the partial derivation. But this seems like a very dubious move from the mathematical perspective.